# How do I share an segment in analytics link with one of my customers?

Tags: google-analytics

How do I share an analytics link with one of my customers? The problem that each customer of my portal has a segment like this: garage.inf.br/home/?pcr=polepress the segments are these "/? Pcr = customer

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are misusing the word `segment` in Analytics, however, as I understand what you need, that is to give different views for different sections you can create different **Views** (in Google Analytics Universal) and insert a filter in each view that includes only those with the path of interest.